# Delete unwanted apps completely

Tags: icloud, iphone

My child accidentally downloaded an inappropriate software and I want to delete all history of me ever having it. How can I do this?

Comment: Did your child download this inappropriate software to iPhone as your tag suggests or to Mac?

Comment: Welcome to the community Lucy. You may want to read [How to ask a good question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Unfortunately, as it stands, it lacks all the information we need to be able to help. For example, do you use [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060)? You also need to confirm what device your child downloaded the app on (your iPhone 6s Plus, a Mac, something else)? Did they use their own Apple ID or yours? Finally, when you say _I want to **delete all history** of me ever having it,_ what do you really mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky under OS X/macOS. If you are not tech savvy, try a [third party app](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25276/appcleaner).

Otherwise, open the Terminal (search for it via Spotlight), and then paste following line:

```
sudo find / -iname "NAME_OF_YOUR_APP" >> ~/Desktop/t.txt
```

Replace NAME_OF_YOUR_APP with the name your actual app you want to delete. Afterwards, you'll see a text file at your Desktop. Open it. Here you have all paths of the app you try to delete. Go via the Finder to every place and delete the files by hand.

> Be careful and make sure the files are really the once from the app
>   and not duplicates from other apps in your system.